# How to add a floating button in UITableViewController which does not scroll when table is scrolled?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently there is a `UITableViewContoller` with many sections and rows.

What is the best way to add a button which floats on top of the table view. This button should not scroll when the cells are scrolled.

Currently I have the following code and with this the button still scrolls:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(viewForFooter)
}
```

the `viewForFooter` is a separate view which contains the button which needs to be floating. Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want a button "over-laid" on your table view? So when you scroll the rows, they are partially hidden behind the button? Or do you want the button in a "footer view" that stays at the bottom of the table?

Comment: @DonMag I'm would like to implement the "over-laid" version on my table view. Where cells are partially hidden behind the button. Due to certain requirements of the project, I'm unable to use a ViewController and add a button as a sibling view of a tableView.

Comment: Just curious... Did you give my answer a try?

Comment: @DonMag I tried and the view persists throughout the app. How can this be dismissed when I move to another ViewController. Thank you for your solution. It works for my needs.

Comment: Well, gee... yes, you have to remove it when you go to another view controller. Make sure you keep a reference to it, and then you should be able to do `viewForFooter.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option if you really don't want to use a UIView with subviews...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
        print("adding view-with-button to keyWindow")
        window.addSubview(viewForFooter)
        viewForFooter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
        viewForFooter.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    }

    // other stuff...
}
```

This will add the view as a subview of the "keyWindow" at 40,120, and will "hover" there while you scroll the table. I am assuming your `viewForFooter` is properly instantiated and you have the necessary constraints set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a viewController that will contain the tableView as a subView and then You can add you floating button as a subview of the viewController

Comment: Due to a requirement of my project, I would not want to use a plain ViewController. I'm aware of that solution where the `UITableView` and `UIButton` are added as siblings to the `UIViewController`. For this requirement I need to implement it on top of a `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.btnPickup = UIButton()
        self.btnPickup?.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 75, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 150, width: 50, height: 50)
//        self.btnPickup?.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
        self.btnPickup?.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "add_user"), for: .normal)
        self.btnPickup?.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.btnPickup?.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: (self.btnPickup?.titleLabel?.font.fontName)!, size: 50)
//        self.btnPickup?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.btnPickup?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
//        self.btnPickup?.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.btnPickup?.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        self.btnPickup?.clipsToBounds = true

//        self.btnPickup?.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        self.btnPickup?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DirectoryViewController.btnTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        print(self.navigationController?.view.subviews.count ?? "error")
        self.navigationController?.view.superview?.insertSubview(self.btnPickup!, at: (self.navigationController?.view.subviews.count)!)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.btnPickup?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly this problem.  I'm using Interface Builder
 and Auto Layout to place it  so, it is not a programtic solution like the ones suggest by my colleagues:

The button must be placed at the same level as the UITableView. Take care where you place it in the hierarchy as depicted below:  It can not be below the Table View in the hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: in your solution, `Home` is a type of `UIViewController`. I'm aware of how floating is done in the case of `UIViewController` by making the `UIButton` as a sibling to `UITableView` in the parent `UIView`. However, the solution I'm looking for is to use a `UITableViewController`. Thank you for the response.

Comment: okay, in storyboard if you check what Home is... it is a ViewController which you dragged from object library from right bottom corner. I'm looking for a TableViewController dragged from that object library. Not arguing, just clarifying what I'm looking for.

Comment: I totally understand.  But a view is a view.  If you want a button (which is a view) to hover over a UITableView or a UIViewController, its the same.

Comment: UIViewController and UITableViewController are separate. UIViewController comes with a UIView as its top level view. Whereas a UITableViewController does not, its top level view is a UITableView. I am not the one who down voted, but probably they saw that you mixed up difference between using a TableView on top of UIViewController vs an embedded TableView in a UITableViewController.

Comment: O.K. adieu to you my friend.